# Windows Filtering Platform Veto

Tags: c, windows, wfp

I am learning Windows Filtering Platform in kernel mode. Could anyone give me an example of Veto in WFP? I know the below code is Hard Block, but I can't imagine what Veto looks like.

```
 classifyOut->actionType = FWP_ACTION_BLOCK;
 classifyOut->rights &= ~FWPS_RIGHT_ACTION_WRITE;
```

MSDN link for this: [Filter Arbitration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/filter-arbitration)

Comment: "A Veto is a "Block" action returned by the filter when the FWPS_RIGHT_ACTION_WRITE flag was reset prior to calling the filter. A Veto will block traffic that was permitted with a hard permit." In other words, before your filter is called another filter will hard permit an action. When your filter is called you can block it, which is considered a veto.

Comment: @Luke How can I block a connection if the flag FWPS_RIGHT_ACTION_WRITE isn't set ?

Comment: Just set the action to block. That's what a veto is: setting the action to block when the flag is set.

Comment: So the flag is just a warning, it doesn't mean that I can't block the connection if FWPS_RIGHT_ACTION_WRITE isn't set, right ?

Comment: I wouldn't say the flag is a 'warning'; it indicates the intent of a previous filter. You can always block traffic regardless of what a prior filter does: "Traffic can be blocked by a callout filter via a Veto even if a higher priority filter has permitted it."